# Alternative of std::find that works faster

Tags: c++, search, find

I have code that finds the new words in a container and adds them to the class private variable `dict`. The function `Learner::Learn` needs to be optimized so that it runs faster. The elements in the `dict` vector could repeat each other, but 'newWords' should always return the count of the new (non-repeated) words.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Learner {
private:
  vector<string> dict;

public:
  int Learn(const vector<string>& words) {
    int newWords = 0;
    for (const auto& word : words) {
      if (find(dict.begin(), dict.end(), word) == dict.end()) {
        ++newWords;
        dict.push_back(word);
      }
    }
    return newWords;
  }
```

I tried this way, but the execution time is the same:

```
class Learner {
 private:
  vector<string> dict;

 public:
  int Learn(const vector<string>& words) {
    std::size_t index = dict.size();
    dict.resize(dict.size() + words.size());
    vector<string>::iterator nth = dict.begin() + index;
    int newWords = 0;
    for (const auto& word : words) {
      if (find(dict.begin(), dict.end(), word) == dict.end()) {
        ++newWords;
        *nth++ = word;
      }
    }
    return newWords;
  }
```

I should avoid using `push_back()` method somehow.

Comment: Basically, time complexity of both versions is N^2. Try using `std::vector::emplace_back`

Comment: I'm not that sure that `std::vector` is the best choice in your case. The advantage is that the internal storage is contiguous but a `std::string` may allocate it's own internal storage on heap as well. Though for short words, it might store without heap allocation. However, I would compare this to an implementation which uses `std::set<std::string> dict` and/or `std::unordered_set<std::string>` instead. I wouldn't wonder if this is finally faster. Both are usually faster to find something in a larger set of data.

Comment: If both container are sorted (`O(N log N)` to sort them otherwise), [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) would solve your issue in linear time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always keep `words` sorted you could use a binary search for a total runtime of O(n log n), but you have to shift the entire vector to insert things in the middle. (which will bring it back to O(n^2))

You should switch to another container for a significant improvement though:

- `std::set` (O(log n) lookup, O(log n) insert)
- `std::map` (O(log n) lookup, O(log n) insert)
- `std::unordered_set` (O(1) lookup, O(1) insert)

Comment: Note that the unordered set complexities are for average case. Worst case is linear.

Comment: Fair enough, but you'd have to be really unlucky to trigger it with dictionary words.

Comment: @eerorika I wouldn't be afraid too much about worst case of hashing if the words are of a human language. ;-) (The hashing of std shouldn't be that bad.)

Comment: @Scheff You can always use a custom hash function, which is not necessarily as good :) Whether the worst case complexity matters depends on use case.

Comment: @Botje `but you have to shift the entire vector to insert things in the middle.` which brings the total runtime to O(N*N).

Comment: @eerorika The worst case of hash tables was something which prevented me long enough to use them in real-world projects. Once, I really was in trouble and suspected the `std::set` not to be fast enough I gave it try and was surprised how good the std hashing (provided by default with `std::unordered_map`) worked with my real-world data (points of 3d objects). The worst case in mind, _without_ a failed custom hash function, `std::unordered_map` always did a quite good job in my (few) cases.

Comment: @eerorika Good observation. added to the answer.

Comment: @Scheff Indeed. In most cases, measurement is best way to choose between them assuming either is an option. A case where simple measurement is not enough is one where you have hard real time constraints. Also, some cases with potential for denial of service attacks.

Answer (score 1):

[Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a efficient alternative, but not in std, so you have to write it yourself or use external library.

In std, [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)/[`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and unordered versions ([`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)/[`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) might help